# Appending number to a variable name in a loop in perl

Tags: perl, loops

I am writing perl test cases for checking C code . Here I am calling C file multiple times 
with different values and checking whether it returns 1. 
My perl file looks something like this:

```
my $variableCheck1,$variableCheck2,$variableCheck3.....
.
.
.
.
if(($variableCheck1 == 1) && ($variableCheck2 == 1) && ($variableCheck3 == 1).....)
{
   print "Test cases are passed";
}
```

The problem is there are many check variables.
Is there a way so that I can run all the check variables in a loop while appending number to the check variable something like this

```
for($i=1 ; $i < 12 ; $i++)
{
      if($variableCheck_$i   == 1)  
    {
    print "Test cases are passed";

    }
}
```

Append such that for each loop variable name changes depending                                                                         on value $i :variableCheck1,variableCheck2.

Comment: [When you find yourself adding an integer suffix to variable names, think "**I should have used an array.**"](/a/1829927/100754)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be better to use an actual testing library, such as [Test::More](https://perldoc.perl.org/Test/More.html) which will let you know if all of the tests passed, as well as providing many useful testing functions .  Then it is very simple to just iterate over your various parameter values and run tests.  Here is an example which passes various parameters to the `echo` command and then pipes the result to calculator program `bc` to see that addition works correctly:

**test_add.t**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Test::More;
for my $aa ( 1..3 ) {
    for my $bb ( 1..3 ) {
        my $expected = $aa + $bb;
        my $prog = "echo $aa + $bb | bc";
        my $output = `$prog`;
        ok( $expected == $output, "$aa + $bb = $expected" );
    }
}
done_testing();
```

Run the test file:

```
prove -v test_add.t
ok 1 - 1 + 1 = 2
ok 2 - 1 + 2 = 3
ok 3 - 1 + 3 = 4
ok 4 - 2 + 1 = 3
ok 5 - 2 + 2 = 4
ok 6 - 2 + 3 = 5
ok 7 - 3 + 1 = 4
ok 8 - 3 + 2 = 5
ok 9 - 3 + 3 = 6
1..9
ok
ll tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=9,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.05 usr  0.01 sys +  0.04 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.10 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

Answer (score 3):

Any time you are using a long list of numbered variables, then the tool for the job is *not* to dynamically work out variable names - that's called symbolic referencing, and it's nasty.

What you should be doing is using a list of variables.

```
my @variablecheck = ( 1, 2, 1, 3, ); 

foreach my $value ( @variablecheck ) { 
    print "Test passed\n" if $value == 1;
}
```

If you are really set on symbolic naming - [read this](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html) before proceeding - it's from 1998, but it's *still* a bad idea. You can use hashes for a similar purpose - they're good if you've got arbitrary names - but for sequential numeric values, an array is the tool for the job.

And so is using a testing library, like [`TAP::Harness`](https://perldoc.perl.org/TAP/Harness.html) or [`Test::More`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Test/More.html)